# Can a where clause on a join be used in a view

Tags: sql, outer-join, sql-view

I'm attempting to create an SQL view that consolidates a number of separate select queries. I've encountered some difficulty putting clauses from the individual select statements into the database view.

A simplified version of my view is:

```
create or replace view TestView as
select 
 A.Name,
 B.Subscription,
 C.Expiry
from
 TestTableA as A left outer join TestTableB as B on A.ID = B.A_ID
 left outer join TestTableC as C on A.ID = C.A_ID;
```

I've got two problems with the view:

- On the frist join how can I only select record where the Subscription is a specific value AND if it is not that value still retrieve the Name and Expiry columns (in which case the Subscription would be null)?
- On the second join how can I specify I only want the record with the most recent expiry date?

Below is my test schema, sample data and desired result set:

```
create table TestTableA
(
    ID int,
    Name varchar(32),
    Primary Key(ID)
);

create table TestTableB
(
    ID int,
    A_ID int,
    Subscription varchar(32),
    Primary Key(ID),
    Foreign Key(A_ID) references TestTableA(ID)
);

create table TestTableC
(
    ID int,
    A_ID int,
    Expiry date,
    Primary Key(ID),
    Foreign Key(A_ID) references TestTableA(ID)
);

create or replace view TestView as
select 
 A.Name,
 B.Subscription,
 C.Expiry
from
 TestTableA as A left outer join TestTableB as B on A.ID = B.A_ID
 left outer join TestTableC as C on A.ID = C.A_ID;

insert into TestTableA values (1, 'Joe');
insert into TestTableB values (1, 1, 'abcd');
insert into TestTableB values (2, 1, 'efgh');
insert into TestTableC values (1, 1, '2012-10-25');
insert into TestTableC values (2, 1, '2012-10-24');
insert into TestTableA values (2, 'Jane');
```

Desired Results 1:

```
select * from TestView where Subscription is null or Subscription = 'efgh';

Joe, efgh, 2012-10-25
Jane, ,
```

Desired Results 2:

```
select * from TestView where Subscription is null or Subscription = 'xxxx';

Joe, , 2012-10-25
Jane, ,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll write query with simple SQL
If you have SQL Server 2005 or higher, you can use `outer apply` instead of join on subquery with `min()`

```
select 
    A.Name,
    B.Subscription,
    C.Expiry
from TestTableA as A
    left outer join TestTableB as B on A.ID = B.A_ID and B.Subscription in ('abcd', 'efgh') 
    left outer join
    (
        select min(T.Expiry) as Expiry, T.A_ID
        from TestTableC as T
        group by T.A_ID
    ) as C on A.ID = C.A_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace view TestView as
select 
  A.Name,
  B.Subscription,
  C.Expiry
from
  TestTableA as A left outer join TestTableB as B on A.ID = B.A_ID
  left outer join TestTableC as C on A.ID = C.A_ID;
where 
  B.Subscription is not null
  and C.Expiry between (now() - interval 1 minute) and now()
```